# Java :Kill process runned by Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, unix, process

I need to write a code,that

1. run unix process with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar MyServerRunner -port MYPORT");`
2. find PID of the process by executing command from java code `lsof -t -i: MYPORT`
3. and kill him by pid `kill -9 PID` ( also by executing command from java code)
4. and then execute others commands

BUT

if I execute this command by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` my program exits with exit code 137 - this means that when I run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 PID")` I kill process of  My java programm, but not the program, that I run from code.

How can I kill ONLY the process that I run from code ?

P.S. maybe I should use ProcessBuilder ?

Comment: If you are using `Runtime.getRuntime()`to run another Java process then you are doing something wrong. Why can't you just run the class in a `Thread`?

Comment: 1. And if you are killing processes with `-9` you are also doing something wrong. If the process has a port it should also have a shutdown command that can be sent to that port. `kill -9` is an action of last resort for an administrator who knows what he's doing (and logs it). It should not be built into applications. 2. The fact that the started Java process exits with `137` has nothing to do with the fact that you are killing the wrong process.

Answer (score 13):

You can kill a sub-process that you have launched from your java application with `destroy`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar MyServerRunner -port MYPORT");
p.destroy();
```

Also note that it might make sense to run that other code in a separate thread rather than in a separate process.

Comment: `Runtime.exec` does run the other process in another thread. Also note that `p.destroy()` sends `SIGTERM`, not `SIGINT` / `SIGHUP` / `SIGKILL`.

Comment: What I meant is that it might be preferable to run MyServerRunner within the same JVM rather than in a different process, but obviously depends on the details.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.exec("ps|grep <your process name>");`, and then parse the result to get the PID, finally `.exec("kill PID");`

Therefore, your process is killed but android app still alive.

Comment: can you please clarify how to get PID ? , also there is small correction ps | grep

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016 this is what I was looking for. With your answer it gives PID which doesn't match from command line PID. Am not sure why ?  String s = null;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pgrep -f selenium-server-standalone");
  
      BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      
      while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(s);
             }

Comment: As of Java 9, you can just call `proc.pid()` to get the pid.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pid with reflection in unix (I know it is a bad idea :)) and call kill;

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
   new String[] {"java","-classpath",System.getProperty("java.class.path"),... });
Class<?> cProcessImpl = proc.getClass();
Field fPid = cProcessImpl.getDeclaredField("pid");
if (!fPid.isAccessible()) {
    fPid.setAccessible(true);
}
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 " + fPid.getInt(proc));
```

Comment: As of Java 9, you can just call `proc.pid()` to get the pid.